# Difference between Parsing and Passing?

Tags: parsing

I know this is basic knowledge but whenever you give parameters to a method are you 'parsing' them, or are you 'passing' them as 'parsing' could be something different?!

I've just never been overly sure!

Thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are **passing** them.

"Parsing" means trying to interpret text or strings and break it down into data elements of some kind.  (For example, you could parse a string describing a date to turn it into a date object, or parse a file containing source code and turn it into an executable.)

Comment: Sure thing.  Depending on a speaker's accent, this could be a difficult distinction to hear, actually.

Answer (score 3):

Passing. Parsing is breaking up / interpreting  strings.

Answer (score 0):

Each spelling could equally be synonymous e.g. when parsing a date just before passing it into a function.